# why doesn't assignment of int to std::map<string,string> produce a compiler error

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment, stdstring

Attempting to assign an int to a string
`std::string s = 5;`
produces the following compiler error:

`error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} requested`

however assigning an int to the value of a string in a map doesn't.  For example the below code compiles, and worse yet makes the assignment converting the int to a char

```
map <string, string>m;
m["test"] = 5;
```

Shouldn't this be an error?

Comment: Try `std::string s; s = 5;`

Comment: assignment and initialization differ from each other: can't initialize string s = 5, but you can have string s; and then assign s = 5;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shouldn't be an error. `m["test"] = 5;` performs assignment, and `std::string` has an [assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) taking `char`, and `int` could be converted to `char` implicitly.

> ```
> constexpr basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
> ```

On the other hand, `std::string s = 5;` is not assignment but initialization; and `std::string` doesn't have any [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking `int` or `char`.

Comment: oh geez, I completely overlooked that it was the constructor.
however int x=9000, s = x, produces some wild results, so it seems to me that assignment from int and not char is kind of risky, but of course that's a different question

Comment: @user438431 - That specific assignment operator from char to string is a bit odd, and kind of a mistake in the API. It has been briefly considered to remove it, but backward compatibility, and all that...